# Firefox Quantum Uses Huge Amounts of RAM

Tags: firefox, memory

I am using Firefox Quantum on a machine with openSUSE Leap 42.3.

My problem is that Firefox uses a stupid amount of RAM. When I use Chromium I am usually on 2 or max 3 GB of RAM (without doing RAM intense jobs). With Firefox the same jobs require a lot of times up to 5+ GB.

For instance I was simply browsing Facebook and after a while my RAM was at 5.3 GB. I closed just the Facebook tab and it dropped immediately to 1.8 GB.

While using Firefox I have to constantly chech my RAM consumption because after a while it maxes but with Chromium I never have to do that. I have tried playing around with hardware acceleration and such but with no improvement.

Also I want to point out that I have the exact same addons in both browsers.

Comment: On Windows, the only time FF57 has runway memory usage in my experience is when using badly behaved user scripts.

Comment: @DavidPostill, I've had similar experience with FF Quantum.  No user scripts.  Both at home (win10) and at work (win7).  Also experience Quantum freezing up from time to time.  This issues did not happen on prior FF release.  While Chrome behaves as it should.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths The same happens to me. No user scripts.